# composer update не работает

Tags: laravel, composer, artisan

Есть установленный Laravel 5, и в composer.json добавил Html пакет, пробовал
composer update. Но ничего не устанавливается.

E:\4GB\WEB\htdocs\larik.loc>php composer.phar update
Composer could not find the config file: php composer.phar
To initialize a project, please create a composer.json file as described in the https://getcomposer.org/ "Getting Started" section

- к этому artisan перестал работать

как исправить ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Убедитесь что перед выполнением команды, вы зашли в папку с laravel проектом в которой лежит composer.json. Есть подозрение что вы вызываете команду из другой папки.

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего при добавлении информации в composer.json была допущена ошибка. Например, пропущена запятая.